# How do I put legend outside of a bargraph without cut off

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried following
[How to put the legend outside the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-outside-the-plot)
but bargraphs dont seem to work with ax = fig.subplots.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1,25)
fig = plt.figure()
legend_array = ["one","two"]
hours_count = [0, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
plt.bar(x - 0.5, hours_count, 0.5)
plt.bar(x, hours_count, 0.5)
plt.xlabel("count")
plt.ylabel("high priority")
plt.xticks(x, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24])
#plt.legend(labels = legend_array)
# box = ax.get_position()
# ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.6, box.height])
plt.legend(labels = legend_array,loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.title("bargraph of high priority errors")
plt.savefig('test.jpg')
```

[image: BarchartWithCutOffLegend]

I tried a different method but it seems to mangle my image even further

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1,25)
fig = plt.figure()
legend_array = ["one","two"]
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
hours_count = [0, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
ax.bar(x - 0.5, hours_count, 0.5)
ax.bar(x, hours_count, 0.5)
plt.xlabel("count")
plt.ylabel("high priority")
plt.xticks(x, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24])
box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.6, box.height])
ax.legend(labels = legend_array,loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.title("bargraph of high priority errors")
plt.savefig('test.jpg')
```

[image: Graph missing ticks and title and occupying only half the space]

Comment: Have you tried using ``figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80)``? -- these are just example measurements but you can adjust them to your needs

Comment: Calling `plt.tight_layout()` just before saving should help for your first example. The second example is more problematic.

Comment: plt.tight_layout() fixes my issue thank you

Comment: In the future, also consider this: `plt.savefig(..., bbox_inches='tight')`.